# How can I display the name of all services with specific tag in symfony2 form

Tags: forms, symfony, service, formbuilder

I have several services tagged with the same tag. I wonder how to proceed to retrieve the list  of all thoses services and to inject it in a form ?

**Here is an exemple of what I want at the end:**

```
$builder->add('days', 'choice', array(
    'choices' => $SERVICES,
    'multiple' => false,
    'expanded' => false,
    ))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main idea is to define a service that will handle all tagged services of a certain type, and then within the compiler pass add tagged services to this service.

Taking example from the documentation on [Working with Tagged Services](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dependency_injection/tags.html), you may add a method that returns all services :

```
<?php

// ...

class TransportChain
{
    // ...

    /**
     * @return array
     */
    public function getTransports()
    {
        return $this->transports;
    }
}
```

And then from anywhere you have access to the DIC, simply use :

```
// Get access to all services tagged with "acme_mailer.transport"
$transports = $this
    ->getContainer()
    ->get('acme_mailer.transport_chain')
    ->getTransports()
;
```

Of course you will have to tweak all this a bit in order to, perhaps, return strings instead of objects.